# How to return to .bat execution after opening a photo?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have the following code:

```
@echo off
color a
Title test
cls

XnViewPortable Foto.jpg
Timeout /T 3
taskkill /IM xnview.exe
taskkill /IM XnViewPortable.exe
pause
```

What do I want to do: open a photo with a specific software and after a specific time, i want to close the photo and return to the .bat execution.

My problem: The photo opens up but in that moment the .bat execution is suspended and revives just when i manually close the photo.

I somehow managed ONCE to do it exactly how I wanted, i dont know how or why, i used the same code.

I appreciate any suggestion! Thank you!

Comment: use [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) `start "" XnViewPortable Foto.jpg`

Comment: It works! How did u figured it out, please?
What start command actually does?
Thank you very much!

Comment: this is a recurring question in batch the link above ( http://ss64.com/nt/start.html ) explains how it works

Comment: Got it! Thanks again!

Comment: @Marko, programming batch files is no different then learning any other programming language. If you have reference manual and take the time to learn the language you eventually know how to do just about everything.